# Fixing code to fetch data from dom document (getElementby...)

Tags: dom, fetch

url : sayuri.go.jp/used-cars

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

Partial Source code :

```
<td colspan="4">

<h4 class="stk-title"><a href="/used-cars/B37753-Toyota-Wish-japanese-used-cars">Toyota Wish G</a></h4>
</td>

<td colspan="4">
```

I am trying to go through the source code and for each parts of the above i want to save the url e.g : "/used-cars/B37753-Toyota-Wish-japanese-used-cars"

Here is the code i am using but unsuccessful so far

```
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h4");

$titles = array();

   foreach ($p as $node) {
     if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
     if($node->getAttribute('class') == "stk-title") {
       foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
         if ($attr->nodeName == "href") {
            array_push($titles , $attr->nodeValue); 
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }


print_r($titles) ;
```

It should give me an array containing all the urls of each car : ("/used-cars/B37753-Toyota-Wish-japanese-used-cars" , "" , "" ......)

but its returning an empty array - i guess i made a mistake in my code and it can't access the urls.

I also need to save the car name inside a variable e.g : $car_name = "Toyota Wish G"

Comment: Your nodes are <h4> tags, but the href attributes you care about are within the inner <a> tags.

Comment: I'm not very good with php , any idea how to fix the code ? p.s : there are too many <a> tags inside the source code and it will give too many values which is why i'm using the <h4> nodes

Comment: This works but gives way too many results  :  $p = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");

$titles = array();

   foreach ($p as $node) {
  if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
       foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
         if ($attr->nodeName == "href") {
            array_push($titles , $attr->nodeValue); 
           }
         }
       }
     }


print_r($titles) ;

Comment: This might help you out: https://gist.github.com/komlenic/1374083

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@class="itemlist-table"]//h4[@class="stk-title"]/a');

$links = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $links[] = array(
        'href' => $node->getAttribute('href'),
        'text' => $node->textContent,
    );
}

print_r($links);
```